# Batching SAS jobs

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, sas

I'm looking for a simple solution which would enable batching SAS programs, which would run directly from cmd, e.g.,
`"C:\Program Files\SASHome2\SASFoundation\9.4\sas.exe"  -CONFIG "C:\Program Files\SASHome2\SASFoundation\9.4\nls\en\sasv9.cfg" -sysin "C:\Users\Documents\sas\Run_Program.sas" -LOG  "C:\Users\Documents\sas\f2.log"`

However the problem is that i have two SAS files - one representing **config**, and the second - being **program** (config file loads particular data sets, global variables, etc...).

Is there a simple solution how i could automate program running process from cmd using current file structure.

Other considered ideas:
i have considered creating new (dynamic) sas file batch.sas with it's content `%inc "config.sas"; %inc "program.sas"` where "program.sas" is dynamic argument provided for every run.

Comment: Why not just make an autoexec.sas file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly - you are looking to run the config.sas file before the program.sas file?  Your suggestion of doing so via `%inc` is a good one, another approach would be to call your config.sas file on startup by using it as an autoexec, eg as follows:

```
"C:\Program Files\SASHome2\SASFoundation\9.4\sas.exe"  
  -CONFIG "C:\Program Files\SASHome2\SASFoundation\9.4\nls\en\sasv9.cfg" 
  -sysin "C:\Users\Documents\sas\Run_Program.sas" 
  -LOG  "C:\Users\Documents\sas\f2.log" 
  -autoexec "C:\Users\Documents\sas\config.sas"
```

An autoexec file runs once, when the SAS session is initialised.  Your config.sas file could start by calling any relevant / existing autoexec(s) if needed.

Comment: Is there a list of available parameters SAS supports/some non-documented options?

Comment: http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/allprodslang/63337/HTML/default/viewer.htm#syntaxByType-systemOption.htm

Comment: A short question: is there any way how i could run two programs with different autoexec but keep partial result, e.g. table from every job?

Comment: You can switch the autoexec using the command line option above (so yes to part 1), regarding the partial results - that depends how your job is configured.  If you need to keep partial results then you should keep those tables in a staging area rather than SASWORK.  This is done in the job itself.  That said, you can of course go look at the files in sas work if the session is still active - see `%sysfunc(pathname(work))`.  For a more comprehensive answer I suggest asking a new question..

Comment: What about different/multiple sysin, e.g., 1 and 2 programs? I'm aiming for 1st program result table_1 to be seen when running program 2?

Comment: simply create a third program that `%inc`'s the programs you need.. They will run sequentially!

Comment: Well, this makes whole structure a bit too complex (considering xxx of files). Does SAS and %inc support parameters, like args in cmd? I have looked at http://www.mwsug.org/proceedings/2007/appdev/MWSUG-2007-A02.pdf, however the only option i see is generating xxx files consisting of %inc file1; %inc file2;

Answer (score 1):

The autoexec solution is a reasonable one, but I think that unless you are *always* (in every single SAS program/session you ever run) loading exactly the same config, that ultimately the right way to do this is the same way `c` programs have done this for decades with header files.

If you have a `config.sas` that loads datasets for a particular program, that program should include `%include config.sas` at the top.  Then you just batch the program.